# Scraping Instagram title using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using BeautifulSoup, I want to be able to get the title tag of the Instagram page depending on the username. What I'm trying to do is to have a user input a particular username that they want to search for and this will be parsed etc. to return the title tag and check if the username that had been entered by the user is within the title. Instead, I get a TypeError saying that it is 'NoneType' even though the page does exist. Below is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def main():
    username = input("Enter username: ")

    instagram(username)

def instagram(username):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username

    results = requests.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    name = doc.title

    if username in name:
        print(name)
    else:
        print("Not found")

print(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Strangely, when I first tested this it was working completely fine but now it only returns errors or 'None'. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Right after `results = requests.get(url)`, put in `print(results.status_code)`. What does it print?

Comment: it's most probably because:
First: You have `print(name)` at the top level (just after `instagram` method and `name` variable is not defined it this scope
Second: at the end in `if __name__ == "__main__":` you forgot indentation for `main()`

Comment: @MattDo I get a status code of 429 which is probably why it doesn't work? I have been running the program over and over again. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me tell you that scraping data from websites is against the terms of service of most websites, including Instagram. Additionally, the structure of the HTML can change at any time, so this code might stop working if the website changes its structure.

Comment: This fails to answer the OP's question which makes this answer ineffective from receiving any upvotes or useful to any extent possible.